# Работа большого количества процессов одновременно

Tags: c#, многопоточность, backgroundworker

Задача состоит в запуске большого количества процессов (порядка 10 тыс). Делаю тестовый вариант для 100 процессов. Делаю с помощью   BackgroundWorker. Процессы создаются. В рабочем цикле процесса я делаю вывод в отдельный файл для каждого процесса ход выполнения работы с меткой времени, после чего увожу процесс в сон ан 3 сек. 
Проблема в том, что процессы работают не одновременно. По логам в файлах видно, что сначала несколько циклов выполняют процессов 10-12, затем влючаются еще столько же. В итоге последняя десятка процессов начинает работу спустя более минуты после начала работы первых процессов.
Пытался сделать то же самое, используя new Task(my_task).Start(). Результат тот же.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно, чтобы все задачи выполнялись параллельно.

Comment: Параллельное выполнение не появится от простого применения `Task`. Вы не должны применять заклинания, не понимая, как они работают.

Comment: Наверное, всё-таки не процесс (Process), а поток (Thread)?

Comment: BackgroundWorker  использует ThreadPool, как и Task. У пула есть размер по исчерпанию которого задачи становятся в очередь ожидая освобождения потоков. Так что вам путь к Thread при котором будет расход памяти и оверхед на переключение потоков. Ну а на 10тыс все станет колом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы делаете Sleep для процесса, то процесс не освобождается и он все равно занят Windows. Именно ОС и не успевает вам выделить много потоков одновременно. Плюс вы пишите в файл от каждого процесса - это довольно ресурсоемкое занятие.

Попробуйте вместо записи в файл во время отдельного процесса закидывать лог в потокобезопасную коллекцию ConcurrentBag и после работы всех потоков сохранять общий лог.

Чтобы оптимизировать сильнее, надо увидеть ваш код.

Comment: Логи в файлы я сделал, чтобы проверить подозрения, которые возникли еще до этого. Сами файлы мне не нужны. Изначально задача состояла в посылке http-запросов на сервер и по логам сервера было видно, что все работает не так, как задумывалось.

Comment: Одновременно слишком мало запросов приходило.
Похоже, что проблема именно в том, что вы описали по поводу Sleep. А как можно это обойти?

Comment: Я не думаю что это можно обойти. Вот тут довольно неплохо описана причина: http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread638303.html Но мне кажется вы вообще пошли не с того конца. Если ваша задача - нагрузочное тестирование сайта, то есть множество программ для этого, от неплохих консольных (https://github.com/tsliwowicz/go-wrk описание работы с ней - https://habrahabr.ru/post/322266/) до UI с возможностью авторизации (http://jmeter.apache.org/ описание - https://habrahabr.ru/post/165159/)